# Plesk/qmail - Add original recipient to the mail header (required by Tobit David)

Tags: linux, email, email-server

I have a server running Plesk 8 and qmail as the MTA.

Now I switched one domain from multiple POP accounts to only one catchall because the mail app at the customers side (Tobit David) has the ability to deliver the mails to the right user by reading a specific header field (can be configured by the admin - that's me ;)

Most MTA's add the original recipient to the header already (mostly the field is called `X-Delivered-To`) and pleak does this, too. The field is called `Deliviered-To´.

However, there is on problem. Let's say I have a user called John Doe with the email address `john.doe@domain.com`. In the mail header the `Deliviered-To` field does not contain `john.doe@domain.com` but `29-john.doe@domain.com`.

I believe that has something to do with the customer or domain I created in Plesk, since that number is unique for all recipients from this domain, but different for other domains.

Is there a way to tell qmail to add another header value with the original recipient? Or modify the current value of `Deliviered-To`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed! I found this link where someone had exactly the same problem:

http://shyper.net/plesk-x-delivered-to/

Quick solution

- Create the folder `/usr/local/psa/handlers/user-handlers/`
- Create a file `/usr/local/psa/handlers/user-handlers/xdeliveredto` with this content

  ```
   #!/bin/bash
   echo "X-Delivered-To: ${3}"
   cat
  ```
- Make it executable `chmod +x /usr/local/psa/handlers/user-handlers/xdeliveredto`
- Register this file as a handler in plesk

  ```
  /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/mailmng \
       --add-handler --handler-name xdeliveredto --handler-type global \
       --executable /usr/local/psa/handlers/user-handlers/xdeliveredto \
       --context xdeliveredto --hook before-local --priority 30
  ```
- ???
- Profit!